# Archlinux live USB on hdpi display

Tags: arch-linux, tty, fonts

I'm installing Archlinux with live usb on a Dell with hdpi display in UEFI mode. The live usb boot into TTY 1 and, due to hdpi, font is so small that it's almost unreadable. I've read that booting with `nomodeset` should solve the issues but I don't know how to pass it to the live usb.
How do I do that? Our is there another way to get bigger fonts on hdpi display?

Comment: Did you try this? [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Linux_console)

Comment: Thanks I came across the same in the end... I've 22 pixel font now which is still small but at least readable. I'll try the bigger ones in the suggested packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to change the font in `/etc/vconsole.conf` to `latarcyrheb-sun32`:
In `/etc/vconsole.conf`:

```
FONT=latarcyrheb-sun32
```

And after do `sudo systemctl restart systemd-vconsole-setup`.

I hope it will help.

Comment: This works perfectly. This should be marked as the correct answer!